# Administration Structure to list menu items fails to display

Tags: routes, breadcrumbs

When I access admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu this should show a list of all of the menu items and enable re-ordering, enabling, etc. This has stopped working and will only display the top level menu (without styles) and sometime just a blank page.

I think it is related to the number of menu items I have. Checking the database for menu_links shows almost 500 entries. Is there a way around this?

Possibly I need to think differently. I am not actually displaying all of the items on the user menu just the top two levels. But by adding node and hiding them I get the breadcrumbs for 'free'. Is there a better way to handle the breadcrumbs that would enable me to remove excess items from the menus?

Thanks in advance
Andrew W.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify only `breadcrumb`, then you can use one of below module.

[custom breadcrumbs](https://drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs):

> Allows administrators to set up parametrized breadcrumb trails for any
>   **node type, Views, Panels, Taxonomy vocabularies and terms, paths** . This allows node types to have "**Home > User
>   Blog > 2005 > January**" style breadcrumbs on the node view page
>   itself, synchronizing cleanly with custom views or pathauto aliases.
>   Breadcrumb visibility can be customized via a php snippet.

[path breadcrumbs](https://drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs)

> Path Breadcrumbs module helps you to create breadcrumbs for any page
>   with any selection rules and load any entity from the URL!

Comment: Thanks for the pointers to these modules. For now, I decided to reduce the number of pages on the menus and so have avoided the problem with the menu admin failing to display.